# Column Wise Retrieving values from Database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a,b,c and many columns in database with their values as follows:

```
a b c d e 
1 1 1 1 2 
2 2 3 4 1
3 3 3 2 4
4 4 4 5 7
5 5 5 3 8
```

I am trying to retrieve column values as follows:

```
while(rs.next()){
        for(int 1=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)));
        }

        }
```

Output I am getting in list is:

```
 1 1 1 1 2 
    2 2 3 4 1
    3 3 3 2 4
    4 4 4 5 7
    5 5 5 3 8
```

that is I am getting row wise.

But I want my code to retrieve all values of column a and then column b and so on for every column present.

Expected output:

```
a's value
1  
2 
3 
4 
5 
1(b's values)
2
3
4
5
```

.
. and so on for every column. Please help.

Comment: What is `list` how do you print your output?

Comment: forget list as I am dumping this data to xml from list..but when you will print the statement rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)) you will get only row wise values but I want column wise

Comment: what is `rsMetaData` in your code?

Comment: Why not just store the data in 5 different `List`. Then you can print or retrieve it any way you like.

Comment: result set metadata

Comment: @nullpointer must be the ResultSet's metadata object

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I don't have only 5 coulmns . This is only for reference. In actual I have to retrieve from more than 1000 columns

Comment: Well create a `List` of  `List`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson creating a list is not a problem sir..I am getting values in my file row wise but I want to retrieve all values of first column then second column  and so on for every column present

Comment: I know it's not the problem. It's a solution. The other route is to query the DB for one column at a time.

Comment: sir could you please elaborate or if possible could you please explain with an example code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your loop to:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for(int i=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++) { 
        System.out.println(rs.getString(i)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different approaches. I have not tested this code, but the idea is correct.

> Approach one: query for each column individually

```
for(int i=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++){
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT " + rsMetaData.getColumnName(i) +" FROM Table";//run a query for each column
    //Query DB
    .
    .
    .
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)));//Print out specific column's data before moving to the next column.
    }           
}
```

> Approach two: Save `List` into `Map`

```
//Create `Map` and `List`s to go in `Map`. 
Map<String, List<String>> columnHolder = new HashMap();
for(int 1=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++){
    System.out.println(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)));
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList();
    columnHolder.put(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i), tempList);
}       

//Store data into `Map` according to column name.
while(rs.next())
{
    for(int i=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)));
        List<String> list = columnHolder.get(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i));
        list.add(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i)));
    }
}
// Now you can do anything with the `Map`. For example: like print the data it holds.
```